# OSS License for "look but don't use it to compete with us"?

Tags: javascript, open-source

Is there a well known Open Source license that would allow me to open source some mission critical code in such a way that the community could read it, but that would simultaneously prevent competitors from using it to gain an advantage over us?

I'll give you a bit more context. We are developing quite a complex and serious business analytics tool for which we decided to create our own in house javascript MVC framework. As part of the project we also built a bunch of reusable controls that seamlessly integrate with the framework for things like switches, tables, autocomplete search boxes, navigation controls, etc. (think Cocoa controls or jQuery UI).

We'd like to release the framework itself and the controls to the community for better or worse under the Apache2 license, fairly standard stuff there. However, and this is really what I'm asking, we would also like to show the source of our SaaS analytics app (the one that powers our business and generates revenue) for the purpose of demonstrating how a complex enterprise app can be built on top of our framework, for it to be sort of like a rigorous proof-of-concept/case study/demo. But we don't want competitors to just clone the repo and deploy it on their servers with some rebranding and start stealing our customers. Is there a well known open source license that could facility this type of information sharing for the benefit of the community whilst simultaneously precluding competitors from gaining a competitive advantage from it? (I mean obviously our competitors might learn a thing or two and that's fine, but we want to have legal power in case they blatantly copy parts of our code and use it to compete against us; and the judgement of whether they are copying or not should be at our sole discretion).

Comment: You *could* write such a license, but it would be very tricky (how do you define "competitor"? Or "advantage"?). Also: it would **never** be a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) license, because of Freedom 0: The freedom to run the program for any purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at the Microsoft [Reference Source license](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicensing.aspx)..

Microsoft does pretty much what you outlined up there with the .NET library.
But as always with these license questions: 
Don't take the word of a bunch of internet strangers - ask a lawyer familiar with the topic before you do anything you might regret.

Also, on a side-note: With all my love for OSS software - Regardless of what your competitors do, the second they have your source they can blatantly copy you (and they will if you are successful enough). And once that has happened you have to spend a pile of money on lawyers trying to get to your rights.
Especially when it's the heart of an operation, I'd label that as "competitive advantage" and not release it to the public. It's your IP, once you give it out to someone anyone can simply take your ideas and write his own app with it - no license in the world can prevent that (besides stupid patents you probably don't have).

So my advice here would be to just wait a bit and see how the MVC lib turns out.
Look at Ruby on Rails. It's been developed as part of Basecamp at 37 Signals, but the Basecamp source code never became public simply because there is no need for that. If the framework is any good people will use it and you'll get organically to sample applications.

Having real world examples is nice, but especially for JavaScript frameworks you should aim to be pretty backend-agnostic - so it shouldn't really matter if you run ASP.NET MVC or Rails or Node on the backend. The logical consequence is that the backend code is of no real interest to your library users.

They can see the library working on your site, that in itself should be enough to show useful usage patterns.
If you take some parts out of your app and show them to users you'll be fine without the risk of lawyering to get to your rights..

Answer (score 1):

No. The purpose of any Open Source license is to give the code to the community to further develop, fork, or use for other purposes. The whole point of having a license is purely to prevent complete theft of code without attribution. If code that is claimed as original appears down the road can be proven to be based on your work, you have sufficient grounds for legal action.

The best way to demonstrate a proof of concept is to take discrete parts of your work as an overall demonstration of the value of the framework.

***But, I'm no lawyer so I would suggest that you consult with one before doing anything that might jeopardize your business or your job.***